# regular expression in javascript, detecting optional arguments

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm doing replacements on some tokenized strings like below:

```
var myString = "I would like to replace the following token <<start<arg1,arg2 >>> in this string"
OR  
var myString = "The expression has an optional <<start<arg1,arg2,arg3 >>> third argument"
```

Within the token, there are 2 or 3 alphanumeric strings which I would like to capture and pass to the regex callback function:

```
myString.replace(regExExpression, function(m, arg1, arg2, arg3) { 
   return foo(arg1, arg2, arg3); 
});
```

What regex expression will match both versions of myString, capture arg1, arg2, and the optional arg3?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Description

Try this which will put each arg into a group 1 2 or 3 respectively, [see also this regexplanet sample](http://fiddle.re/6e006)

- Each attribute group starts with `<<start<` and ends with `>>>`
- Will match between 2 and 3 groups of comma delimited substrings between the open and close tags, additional groups could be matched by inserting `(?:,([^,>]*))?` between the second and third groups.
- Token 3 is optional

`<<start<([^,>]*)(?:,([^,>]*))(?:,([^>]*))?(?=>>>)`

[image]

Comment: nice graphic, but only arg 3 is optional.  arg 1 and 2 are required.

Comment: updated the answer so that group 2 is required, but leaving group 3 as  optional

Answer (score 0):

I think you just want the regex

```
/<<(.*?)>>>/g
```

This should also work if there are multiple samples per line, but not if they are nested.  If that doesn't cover your actual question, it's because it's a bit unclear.

Comment: I haven't posted to SO for a little while so my SO question asking skills are rusty. I'll polish this question a little. Are there specific points that are unclear?

Comment: @MedicineMan When in doubt, give lots of sample input and sample output that covers all corner cases - that way, answers can be all like 'I know this is what you want, since it processes sample input to sample output' not 'I think this is what you want, it kinda sounds like it is, well here you go!'

Answer (score 0):

I following handles your specific case:

```
  /<<\s*start\s*<\s*(?:([^,>]*))?(?:\s*,\s*([^,>]*))?(?:\s*,\s*([^>]*))?>>>/i
```

I usually sprinkle my REs with \s* to accept free form input. Remove them if you are sure not to need them. I do not think that you can write a single RE to handle an arbitrary number of arguments but you specified a maximum of 3.

My recommendation would be to use the following two stage solution which gives you the extra flexibility of an arbitrary number of arguments :

```
  .replace (/<<\s*start\s*<\s*(.*)?\s*>>>/i, function (m, args) {
     args = args.split (/\s*,\s*/); // array of args
     return  ('{{[' + args.length + '] : ' + args.join (', ') + '}}');
  });
```

And used as follows :

```
"I would like to replace the following token <<start<arg1,arg2 , arg3>>> in this string".replace (/<<\s*start\s*<\s*(.*)?\s*>>>/i, function (m, args) {
         args = args.split (/\s*,\s*/); // arbitrary number of
         return  ('{{[' + args.length + '] : ' + args.join (', ') + '}}');
      });
```

Resulting in :

```
"I would like to replace the following token {{[3] : arg1, arg2, arg3}} in this string"
```